# Python daemon\listener disk usage - tkinter message warning

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter, systemd

so I have a python code, that I use as a systemd service on ubuntu
this act as a daemon\listener to a disk usage. once the disk usage reached
specified % it will pop up a tkinter window warning with "Ok" button -
when clicked on the "Ok" button it will open 'baobab' (Disk Usage Analyzer) - and the
tkinter notification window closes obviously (i'll explain below why that info is here)
and it works in a loop - until the disk usage limit get below the specified %

now here is the main issue for now:
when I run in terminal the code as it is - 'python3 /path/main.py' and then open another
terminal and test with 'fallocate -l 2000G Downloads/Test'
the tkinter pop up the warning notification with the 'OK' button, and when clicked - it opens 'baobab' and all working fine.

but when I insert that exact same code as a systemd service and in terminal do the same fallocate command - the tkinter warning message pops up, but when click on 'OK' button - the click motion is stuck and not closes + it takes longer time to open 'baobab' Disk Usage Analyzer
and when closing baobab it just unclick the 'OK' button in the notification window

now I know there are some complications for systemd services with GUI like tkinter pop window notification... any one got an idea how to reach a solution for that?
the same exact python code works fine as the code, but when doing as service its stuck and misbehave as expected.

here is an example of the python code -

```
def monitor_storage(threshold_percentage=90, check_interval=5):
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.withdraw()

    while True:
        try:
            disk_usage = shutil.disk_usage("/")
            used_percentage = (disk_usage.total - disk_usage.free) / disk_usage.total * 100

            if used_percentage >= 100:
                response = messagebox.showwarning("Storage Alert",
                                                  f"Your storage is FULL \n({used_percentage:.2f}% used)!")
                if response == "ok":
                    open_disk_usage_analyzer()
            elif used_percentage > threshold_percentage:
                response = messagebox.showwarning("Storage Alert",
                                                  f"Your storage is almost full \n({used_percentage:.2f}% used)!")
                if response == "ok":
                    open_disk_usage_analyzer()

            # Check every N seconds
            time.sleep(check_interval)

        except Exception as e:
            # Log any exceptions
            logging.error(f"An error occurred: {e}")
            center_messagebox(tk.Tk(), "Error", f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

any ideas will be appreciated - thanks

Comment: Can you create a minimal example of your code, showing how you are creating a window or starting the other app.

Comment: @AhmedAEK sure thing, I edited the post with the python function 
i have more functions there that don't have direct impact on the tkinter so i posted only the function that works on the logic and tkinter

Comment: How do you start the *disk usage analyzer*? Function from `subprocess` module? Or `os.system()`?  Also you should not create new instance of `Tk()` in the `except` block.

Comment: @acw1668 yes I start the disk usage analyzer function from `subprocess` in the other function open_disk_usage_analyzer()

Comment: you don't have a proper eventloop, so maybe use `window.update()` or `window.update_idletasks()` to flush pending events after the messagebox is closed.

Comment: @AhmedAEK that actually helped thanks alot!!
also another (maybe small) issue, when the service active, and first time the window notification pops up and click on "OK" it takes about 10sec more or less to open disk usage analyzer, but only the first time, when i then close that window and the pop up shows again, click on "OK" - disk usage analyzer opens up immediately after the click
- any idea why thats happening?

Comment: If it shows up in htop but not on screen then it's probably just a slow app, if it doesn't show up in htop then you probably need a proper tkinter eventloop with `.after` and `Popen`

Comment: @AhmedAEK yes it shows up in htop right when click on "OK"
but the app it self pops up after long wait... and again, it happens only the first time. but subsequent times it opens quickly